# Check one attribute from a list is set

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a model like so

```
class Person extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  public $desk_no;
  public $mobl_no;
  public $faxx_no;
}
```

I want to add a validation rule which would read something like this in English

> One of the *_no attributes is required; I don't care which one.

How do I go about that in [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2)?

Comment: Have You tried add custom validator? if(a is null && b is null && c is null) $this->addError()?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a hack but you can use the required validator with conditional validation:

```
public function rules() {
    $oneOfUs = ['desk_no', 'mobl_no', 'faxx_no'];
    return [
        ... //Your other rules here
        [$oneOfUs, 'required', 'when' => function($model, $attribute) use ($oneOfUs) {
            foreach (array_diff($oneOfUs, [$attribute]) as $f) {
                return !!($model->$f);
            }
            return false;
        }]
    ];
}
```

The above code works since the condition function will return true if any attribute except the current one is set. This will in turn run the`required` validator on the current attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you could use such validation for example

```
['desk_no', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
    return is_null($model->mobl_no)&&is_null($model->faxx_no);
}, message => "One of the *_no attributes is required; I don't care which one." ],
```

but if this logic can change, i prefer custom validator